# Show gridlines over graph in chart.js, show bold x-axis label in chart.js, mixure of intersecting graph colors in chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

Well very new to `chart.js`. having some doubts on this and can't figure out how.

- **well i want my graph looks like as in the image below.** `image1.jpg`

[image]

- **This is how i styled till now.** `image2.jpg`

[image]

- **Required stylings.**

  1. I don't want gridlines to expand after scale lines as in `image1.jpg`.
  2. custom axis label font weights.
  3. Gridlines overlapping the graph as like in `image1.jpg`.
  4. Rich Mixture of colors where graphs overlaps each other. (it is there but not as `image1.jpg`).

Please help to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've generated graph by,

```
const canvasmixedBarLine: any = document.getElementById('mixedBarLine');

const ctxmixedBarLine: any = canvasmixedBarLine.getContext('2d');

const mixedBarLine = new Chart(ctxmixedBarLine, {});
```

try putting this line after that:

```
ctxmixedBarLine.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
```